How to remove rust on flashing and siding and do I caulk?
Our siding is board and batten style hardie board painted white. The base of the house where it meets the metal (flashing?) is very stained. I thought before it was dirt, but I see now it is rust. And in the worst spots there is mildew/mold.  I know water gets on that metal base flashing and slides in And the harder board just soaks in it too. The stains are not present on our porches where it’s always dry.
Has this been installed wrong? Should I caulk it and repaint? I have since tried scrubbing it using a CRL spray and a clean toilet brush, and some comes off but most is still there.
Edit to add: I have discovered the skirting has swollen and tilted the flashing inward. (See illustration) I still don’t know proper course of action though


water shouldn't sit in there do you have weap holes in it? is there space between the metal and the grade?  what is the front piece of wood / hardie?  a few more pics would help.

@FreshCodemonger The installer of the flashing did not pitch the flashing so it drains off the top properly. It will hold water, but it will only get to the framing at the corners or laps in the longer runs, since water seeks it own level and will get into anything, given the opportunity. I am writing this for the OP as well. It does look like Hardie/cement board. The coloration is from the water sitting and drying up over time, getting darker as time goes on. Do not caulk it, it is a big mistake if you do, caulk holds in water as well as keeping it out when it fails, or a spot is missed.

@Jack I have added an illustration to show details. The skirting has expanded due to soaking up moisture. This has caused the board and flashing to tilt. Water pools then wicks into siding causing the rust. The bottom of these boards isn’t sealed in any way that I can tell. Should it be? Maybe even just painting the underside would have prevented this? I do not know the best course of action. Lowe’s employee suggested clean/caulk/paint. But it sounds like that is a bad idea for the the reasons you stated. Just..don’t know what i should do though. :/

@FreshCodemonger I added an illustration (too late for a pic at the moment) see my comment to Jack for details. (It wouldn’t let me tag both  in one comment)

You could remove the batter board and slightly bevel the top of it so the back height is slightly taller than the front height and re-install.  That would allow the Z flashing to come back down to a positive drainage slope.  There are now cellular pvc fascia boards which can't swell so replacing with that could also be a good option.
